# Java check if string is valid file

Tags: java

I want to check if a string is a valid file pattern, what i want is:

if `string = "/abc/def/apple.xml"` then `return TRUE`

if `string = "/abc/def/"`  then `return FALSE`

if `string = "/abc/def"`  then `return FALSE`

My code:

```
String filepath = "/abc/def/apple.xml";
File f = new File(filepath);

if(f.isFile() && !f.isDirectory())
 return true;
else
  return false;
```

With my code i set string as `/abc/def/apple.xml` or `/abc/def/`, both also return `false`, not really sure why

Comment: i tried if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) too, not work either

Comment: Where is the file located?

Comment: Do you want to check if the mentioned file exists at the given location or do you want to checking the string and see if that looks like a file name?

Comment: actually this filepath is a string stored in database, i just want to validate the string before proceed.

Comment: @rajesh i want to check the string and see if that looks like a file name

Comment: I think your code checks for actual file existence and what you mean by this line  "if file exist in a string" is checking the String str that it contains any file extension.

Comment: @user3172596 Do you not care if the file exists just that is looks like a file path?

Comment: so you only want to check a string and decide if it's a file or folder based on it's name? example if it ends with .xml then it's a file? that won't work since you can name directories .xml as well... do you not care about the existance of the file at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use Java 7 (or better) you can use the new new IO. There is a tutorial from Oracle about this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
String filePath = "yourPath/file.txt"; 
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
System.out.println(Files.exists(path, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are pretty sure about filepath that it contain .xml than you can do your task in that manner also

```
String path="abc/bcd/efg.xml";
boolean temp=path.endsWith(".xml") ;
```